# load css stylesheet in twig

Tags: symfony, twig

I'm trying to load a css file depending on who's connected.
So I've concateneted my url path with the variable, I don't seem to et any erros but the css doesnt show.
If you've got any advice.

cheers

My code:

```
<head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}-S...</title>
        {% block stylesheets %}
            {% stylesheets
                "@xxxMainBundle/Resources/css/general/*"
            %}

            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">

            <!--link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha256-MfvZlkHCEqatNoGiOXveE8FIwMzZg4W85qfrfIFBfYc= sha512-dTfge/zgoMYpP7QbHy4gWMEGsbsdZeCXz7irItjcC3sPUFtf0kuFbDz/ixG7ArTxmDjLXDmezHubeNikyKGVyQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"-->
            {% if (app.session.get('courtierStyle') is defined) and (app.session.get('courtierStyle') is not null) %}
                {% set varStyle = "Sygedel/MainBundle/Resources/css/courtier/"~ app.session.get('courtierStyle') %} /*I set the var here*/

                    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ varStyle }}"/> /* and pass it in th elink tag here"

            {% endif %}
        {% endblock %}
        <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="{{ asset('favicon.ico') }}" />
    </head>
```

Comment: You should look in the resulting HTML if the filename (varStyle) is displayed as expected.

Comment: inspect your code so that you will get the idea that your CSS loaded correctly or not

Answer (score 0):

As above you need to check if the variable has the correct value and execute assets:install to copy the assets in your bundle to web/bundlename directory(where symfony load the assets) .After that you only have two options.

> Option #1(the variable is a full asset reference)

like `/mypath/web/favicon.ico`

in this case you need to use the variable like you are doing

```
...
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ varStyle }}"/> 
...
```

> Option #2 is a reference from web folder

like `favicon.ico # when you use asset('favicon.ico')  the result is the option #1`

in this case you need to use the variable like this:

```
...
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset(varStyle ) }}"/> 
    ...
```

after those changes you code should look like this

```
{% set varStyle = "bundlename"~ app.session.get('courtierStyle') %} /*I set the var here*/
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset('varStyle ')}}"/>
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You can locate your css file in to YourBundle/Resources/public/... and run app/console assets:install and access your css via path /bundle_name/... But are you sure that you need to load different css files depending on who's connected? Maybe you need render the different templates instead?